# result be null and program did not enter if statement

Tags: java, servlets

// dopost methode

```
@Override
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        String password = null;
       response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        String parm;
        parm=request.getParameter("user_name");
        String User_name=parm;
        parm=request.getParameter("National");
        int National_ID=Integer.parseInt(parm);
        try{
                Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
     con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;databaseName=My_Project;integratedSecurity=true;applicationName=WebApplication2;");
    String sqlquery="select * from Users where First_Name='" + User_name + "'and National_ID='" +National_ID + "'";
        PreparedStatement ps=con.prepareStatement(sqlquery);
    rs=ps.executeQuery();
        if(rs.next()){

            password=rs.getString(9);

         }
    }catch(SQLException e){} catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Forget.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
             //ds.ss(User_name, National_ID);
             //String password=ds.password;
            //  String password=new DataBase().(User_name,National_ID);
            /* TODO output your page here. You may use following sample code. */
            out.println("<!DOCTYPE html>");
            out.println("<html>");
            out.println("<head>");
            out.println("<title>Servlet Forget</title>");            
            out.println("</head>");
            out.println("<body>");
           out.println("<h1>Your Password  " + password + "</h1>");
            out.println("</body>");
            out.println("</html>");

    }
```

// result still null

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/28914778/1391249

Comment: You are using a prepared statement though you are concatenating values in the said query statement for no precise reason.

Comment: Please don't repost questions. A lot of this code makes me cringe. A suggestion would be to use a breakpoint, and to make sure your jdbc connection is valid.

Answer (score 0):

First of all I would like to tell you, please stick to proper java conventions when you code. And when you post, please post it with proper formatting. use exception handling with proper exception messages or stacktrace to identify the issues.

I just changed your post method. Use it and see whether it works. Note: I assume your JDBC connection works pretty well without any isse:

```js
@Override
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
   
 response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
 PrintWriter out = null;

 String password = null;
 String userName = request.getParameter("user_name");
 String nationalVal = request.getParameter("National");
 int national=0;
   if(national != null && !national.isEmpty()){
   national = Integer.parseInt(nationalVal);
   }
  
    ResultSet rs= null;
    Statement st=null; 
    Connection con = null;
 
    try{
     out = response.getWriter();
        Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
  con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;databaseName=My_Project;integratedSecurity=true;applicationName=WebApplication2;");
  
  String sqlQuery="select password from Users where First_Name='"+ User_name +"' and National_ID=" +National_ID ;
        st = con.createStatement();
  rs = st.executeQuery(sqlQuery);
  
        if(rs.next()){
   password = rs.getString(9);
        }
  
    }catch(SQLException e){
   e.printStackTrace();
    }
 
  out.println("<!DOCTYPE html>");
  out.println("<html>");
  out.println("<head>");
  out.println("<title>Servlet Forget</title>");            
  out.println("</head>");
  out.println("<body>");
  out.println("<h1>Your Password  " + password + "</h1>");
  out.println("</body>");
  out.println("</html>");

    }
```

reposting answer for your reposted question.

Comment: at first really thank you for your help but the problem still found result still null

Comment: what are the values you get for userName and national values..? print it and  let me know.